# contributor in amsart cannot work

Tags: amsart

I wrote an article, and one author contributed to write an appendix. He suggested that I applied the command `\contrib[With an appendix by]{sb.}`.  However, I don't know why it does not work. When I compile, it reads: undefined control sequence.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{names}
\contrib[With an appendix by]{sb}
\maketitle
content
\end{document}
```

Do I need to input some new packages to run the `\contrib`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently adding `\makeatletter\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs\makeatother` to your preamble lets you compile. I found this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/WYOnYn9pJQU).

Comment: `amsart` does appear to have a `\contrib` command, as described in the [documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf) (page 20)

Comment: @MaxSnippe Yes! It works! Thanks a lot! I also observed your link, and it solved my problem! Unfortunately, there are few questions on this problem...

Comment: @DENGYa Great, I've added an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be solved by adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother
```

to your preamble.

According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/WYOnYn9pJQU), it is a bug in the `ams` classes. All credits to Enrico Gregorio at the Google forum.

Comment: Oh, that's eleven years ago! I completely forgot about that!

Comment: actually, the bug was first reported in september 2005.  i've been trying to get it fixed in the ctan version ever since, and can only say i'm sorry that my pleas have been overruled.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old bug of `amsart.cls` that I appear to have analyzed back in 2007 in a [comp.text.tex thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/WYOnYn9pJQU).

Here are the relevant lines in `amsart.cls`, where the error is apparent on line 495:

```
480 \newcommand\contrib[2][]{%
481   \def\@tempa{#1}%
482   \ifx\@empty\@tempa
483   \else
484     \ifresetcontrib \@xcontribs
485     \else \global\resetcontribtrue
486     \fi
487   \fi
488   \ifx\@empty\contribs
489     \gdef\contribs{#1 #2}%
490   \else
491     \g@addto@macro\contribs{\and#1 #2}%
492   \fi
493   \@wraptoccontribs{#1}{#2}%
494 }
495 \def\wraptoccontribs#1#2{}
```

The correct code should be

```
495 \def\@wraptoccontribs#1#2{}
```

The macro is just a hook, possibly used for some in-house processing if the paper is to be inserted as a contribution to some volume.

The workaround is adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{names}
\contrib[With an appendix by]{sb}
\maketitle
content
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a lot more clear than my answer! Thanks for the clarification.