# How to correctly add an author of an appendix to the titlepage?

Tags: formatting, titles, amsart, author

Together with another author, I am currently writing a paper using the *amsart* document class. We've added both of us as authors using the \author command.  A third person, who is not an author of the main part of the paper, contributes an appendix. We would like to add a phrase like "with an appendix by ..." to the titlepage to mention him as the author of the appendix.

How to do this properly?

I've seen others include the phrase in the title, which I don't find optimal.

The example below corresponds quite well to what I want. I have created it using the following primitive hack:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Alice Foo}

\author{Bob Bar\smallskip\\
\MakeLowercase{with an appendix by} Foo Bar}

\title{This is the title}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract. 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\appendix

\section{This is the appendix title}
\smallskip
\begin{center}by \textsc{Foo Bar}\end{center}
\medskip
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you attach screenshots of what you currently have and what you woud like to have?

Comment: @antshar: sure, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You might find answer here.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component `\contrib` (for "contributor") has been supported for all AMS document classes since 2010.  The input would be

\contrib[with an appendix by]{Foo Bar}

This is documented in the AMS Author Handbook (for Journals) in section 4.4.  The handbooks are included in TeX Live and can be accessed by `texdoc -l amscls-doc`, which will list all the versions; the journals version is the first listed.

As reminded in a comment, there's a longstanding bug that makes this not work properly (yet).  Add this to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother
```

(The problem has been on the AMS class bugs list since 2005.  I understand that an update is underway, ... slowly ..., and may appear later this year.  If that happens before this is final, and the new version of `amsart` is installed, the patch will need to be removed.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for; however I had to add the following to the preamble to make it work (as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439010/contributor-in-amsart-cannot-work):  \makeatletter
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother

Comment: @BK -- Ugh.  That's been known for years.  I keep hoping that AMS management will decide that issuing an updated class package is a good idea and will happen soon.  I've reported the problem though.  Thanks for the reminder.